# Unable to scale application - containercreating

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, kubernetes-deployment

I am using this deployment template (is that what its called?).  Two pods are running but two are stuck at containercreating.  If I scale to 2 replicas, 1 is running and 1 is stuck at containercreating.  How to have all 4 pods running?

This declaration creates a PV in AWS and attaches the pvc.  Data is persistent.  But unable to get past the containercreating issue.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-497xt   1/1     Running             0          2m
activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-b4tpx   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1m
activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-hprpv   1/1     Running             0          1m
activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-vdtcs   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          1m
```

Describe gives this:

```
$ kubectl describe deployments activemq-deployment
Name:                   activemq-deployment
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Wed, 27 Feb 2019 21:49:11 -0800
Labels:                 app=activemq
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               app=activemq
Replicas:               4 desired | 4 updated | 4 total | 2 available | 2 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=activemq
  Containers:
   activemq:
    Image:        activemq:1.0
    Port:         8161/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /opt/apache-activemq-5.15.6/data from activemq-data (rw)
  Volumes:
   activemq-data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  amq-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   activemq-deployment-58cc677d85 (4/4 replicas created)
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  3m8s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set activemq-deployment-58cc677d85 to 1
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  103s  deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set activemq-deployment-58cc677d85 to 4
```

Declaration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: activemq-deployment
  labels:
    app: activemq
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: activemq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: activemq
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000
      containers:
      - name: activemq
        image: activemq:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8161
        volumeMounts:
        - name: activemq-data
          mountPath: /opt/apache-activemq-5.15.6/data
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: activemq-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: amq-pv-claim

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: amq-nodeport-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: activemq
  ports:
  - port: 8161
    targetPort: 8161
  type: NodePort
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: amq-pv-claim
spec:
  #storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Comment: Hi, can you check the nodes, `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl describe pods $CREATING_STATE_POD`

Comment: I'm wondering if it may have to do with the PVC? You have one PVC with access mode `ReadWriteOnce`. See the documentation for `StatefulSet`, where a `PersistentVolumeClaimTemplate` creates a `PersistentVolumeClaim` for each replica. I suspect you might need to create a new PVC for each replica, but I'm not 100% sure.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/

Comment: @SureshVishnoi, Warning  FailedMount  3m50s (x292 over 11h)  kubelet, ip-172-20-35-134.us-west-2.compute.internal  Unable to mount volum                                         es for pod "activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-vdtcs_default(c5e0deb4-3b1c-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556)": timeout expired waiting f                                         or volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"activemq-deployment-58cc677d85-vdtcs".

Comment: @JonathanMosenkis, I've tried the stateful set before with no luck.  I'll give it a shot again.  thanks.

Comment: I would check if the volume is created or not `kubectl get pv`  as it's say that **waiting for volumes to attach** it could be that volume is not getting attached to the node after than it is mounted inside the pod

Comment: The pv's are all bound.                               
pvc-aa687a5e-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/activemq-data-activemq-sful-0   gp2                     2d
pvc-b9cece61-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/activemq-data-activemq-sful-1   gp2                     2d
pvc-ce00653c-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/activemq-data-activemq-sful-2   gp2                     2d

Answer (score 0):

Use StatefulSets for persisting the state of the container. Deployment is not recommended for running stateful containers

Comment: I have been trying to bring up the same image for activemq that works fine as a deployment.  But when I use the same image as a stateful set, activemq UI does not show up and when I login to the pod and do a netstat, not all ports are listening.  What could be the reason?  When I run 'create -f', I can see on AWS 3 EB volumes are created for each of the replicas and they are all running fine.  I took the declarative template for nginx from kube docs and replaced with my activemq docker image.  of course, i changed mountPath to the activemq related one.

Comment: Share the output from kubectl get pvc

Comment: [support@10.0.165.21 deployments]$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                            STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
activemq-data-activemq-sful-0   Bound    pvc-aa687a5e-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            gp2            1m
activemq-data-activemq-sful-1   Bound    pvc-b9cece61-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            gp2            1m
activemq-data-activemq-sful-2   Bound    pvc-ce00653c-3df6-11e9-bb1e-02d9e4741556   2Gi        RWO            gp2            50s